# Django manage.py migrate command cannot access Linux environment variables

Tags: python, django, linux, environment-variables

Python cannot access environment variables while running any command. For example, after running

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

an error occurs:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, "Access denied for user 'dbmasteruser'@'0.0.0.0' (using password: YES)")
```

But if I insert a plain string value for database password instead of `os.environ.get('PASSWORD')`, command works fine.

All environment variables are written in `setenv.sh` file, but I have also tried to set them alternatively using command `export PASSWORD=password`.

Executing command using `sudo` doesn't work either.

However, Apache deployment server can read those environment variables without any issues, but the problem occurs while running migrations or any other command. How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you have correct password in file setenv.sh?

Comment: The password is correct, because Apache server reads it from setenv.sh